# level order binary tree traversal using queue

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, queue, iteration

i'm trying to do level order traversal using queue. but only the first value is printed i.e 10. After that dequeue() function is called but still the values are not getting printed. Apparently there's some problem with dequeue() function. please help.

all the functions are working.

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<stdlib.h>
            #define max 100
            int a[max];
            int front=-1;
            int rear=-1;
            struct node
            {
                int data;
                struct node *left, *right;
            };
            struct node *newNode(int data)
            {
                struct node *nn;
                nn=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                if(!nn)
                    return;
                nn->data=data;
                nn->left=nn->right=NULL;
                return nn;
            };
            void enqueue(struct node *root)
            {
                a[++rear]=root;
                front++;
            }
            struct node *dequeue()
            {
                printf("inside dequeue\n");
                struct node *temp;
                temp=a[front];
                front++;
                return temp;
            }
            int isempty(){
                return(front==-1);
            }
            void levelorder(struct node *root)
            {
                struct node *temp=NULL;
                if(!root)
                    return;
                enqueue(root);
                while(!isempty())
                {
                    temp=dequeue();
                    printf("%d\t",temp->data);
                    if(temp->left)
                        enqueue(temp->left);
                    if(temp->right)
                        enqueue(temp->right);
                }
            }
            int main()
            {
                int data;
                struct node *root=newNode(10);
                root->left = newNode(11);
                root->left->left = newNode(7);
                root->right = newNode(9);
                root->right->left = newNode(15);
                root->right->right = newNode(8);
                levelorder(root);
                return 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some fault in your logic behind the implementation of the queue. I can give you some suggestions.

```
        int front=0,rear=0;

        void enqueue(struct node *root)
        {
            a[rear]=root;
            rear++;
        }

        struct node *dequeue()
        {
            //handle case where queue is empty
            printf("inside dequeue\n");
            struct node *temp;
            temp=a[front];
            front++;
            return temp;
        }

        int isEmpty(){
            return(front==rear);
        }
```

To make it more reliable with the size of the array you should use the modulus function with indexes like this.

```
        int front=0,rear=0;

        void enqueue(struct node *root)
        {
            a[rear%max]=root;
            rear++;
        }

        struct node *dequeue()
        {
            //handle case where queue is empty
            printf("inside dequeue\n");
            struct node *temp;
            temp=a[front%max];
            front++;
            return temp;
        }

        int isEmpty(){
            return(front==rear);
        }
```